# jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations does not exist

Tags: java, nashorn

I am very new to Java and using IntelliJ
I am running an open source file.

but the building giving this error

> Error:(21, 43) java: package jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations does
>   not exist

I tried installing JDK 11 but still getting the same error.

What I have to do so the system recognize this library?

Comment: Hello - it's unclear what it is exactly that you want to achieve. In any case, the Nashorn JavaScript implementation is no longer part of Java since version 11. See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335 for details. Which Java version did you work with before installing 11?

Comment: the open source seems since 2017, is there a way to include nashorn to the current java version

Comment: Same issue any solution?

Comment: Luckily in my case the import wasn't being used, so I deleted it and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you so many months later, I think you used the spring web initializer to create a new project, at the test class you will find you are importing that class, delete the import statement and then delete the test case, then try to re build the project and it should run, as it was mentioned at the comments the class is not longer part of Java 11, probably later on you can try to use Junit for some of your test cases

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was running a Gradle task from the command line instead of from Intellij IDEA. Switching the JAVA_HOME to the correct one (Java 8 in my case) solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding `JAVA_HOME` on my env fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

jdk.nashorn is removed in java 15

Comment: Though this could do with a bit more about how they know it was removed in Java 15, this can already help people who are here because they get the same error message.